# Focus on "On Screen Keyboard" Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I hope,I will get answer for below question:

I am working on Android 2.2,and in one of my application has edit box. So i would like to write text in this edit box.

But there are following problems :

1. As my device has only Navigation Keys,Menu key,Back key,Volume keys etc.
2. Device is not touch screen.

Now my question is: "How can i get focus on "On Screen Keyboard" with the help of navigation keys ?

Thank you in advance for your answers